# Counterexample that violates monotonicity for $\rho(X)=\sigma[X]-E[X]$

Tags: random-variables

Can anybody think of an example of X and Y that violates the monotonicity condition for $\rho(X)=\sigma[X]-E[X]$? That is, I want to find a pair of rv's $X$, $Y$ such that $X\leq Y$ (the random variable  stochastically dominates the random variable ) and $\rho(Y)>\rho(X)$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Typo in the last inequality.

Comment: Thanks. It's fixed now!

Comment: Do you want $\rho (Y) \leq \rho (X)$ or $\rho (X) \leq \rho (Y)$? Your inequality has  simple counter-examples.

Comment: I want a pair that violates the condition, so $\rho(X)<\rho(Y)$

Comment: Let $X=-1$ and $Y=0$. Then, $X\leq Y$, $\sigma(X)=\sigma(Y)=0$ and $\rho(X)=0-(-1)=1$, while $\rho(Y)=0$.

Comment: But that would make $\rho(X)>\rho(Y)$. I am trying to find the opposite!